# Cisco 2960 reload without rebooting

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, reboot

I have a Cisco 2960X (48) with a weird behavior.

I keep seeing alerts from my nagios telling me that the "site" is DOWN, then UP.
It happens almost 10 times a day.
It looks like the switch is rebooting, people are losing their IPs, all ports are turning off, then yellow, and green.

The config is clean and no ports are err-disabled.
No stack, no routing, two SFPs with no problems.

I first thought it was the power supply or the inverter, but it's not.
then i thought the switch rebooted itself for some reason, but no.

the result of : sh version

ROM: Bootstrap program is C2960X boot loader
BOOTLDR: C2960X Boot Loader (C2960X-HBOOT-M) Version 15.2(4r)E3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc4)

SW-SLOUS uptime is 1 week, 4 hours, 35 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System restarted at 10:30:28 UTC Wed Dec 9 2020
System image file is "flash:/c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-4.E8/c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-4.E8.bin"
Last reload reason: power-on

I did a hard reboot on wednesday 9. But the uptime shows 1 week and 4 hours.
So I guess the switch did not reboot, can someone please help me with that, I do not have cisco tac.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
System returned to ROM by power-on System restarted at 10:30:28 UTC Wed Dec 9 2020
```

It looks like the switch did reboot on Dec 9 (that was a week ago).  You can try looking at the log.

```
show logging
```

If it's not enabled, try this:

```
config t
logging buffered information
```

The log should show you what happens during the event.  I suspect the switch is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's me, I did the reboot on wednesday 9.

But it keeps rebooting every hour, every day.

Seems like the logs are enabled, but it only shows the interfaces states.

So I assume that the switch keeps "reloading" (no rebooting) but I can't see it in the logs...

Comment: Do the logs show any event before the last "reload"?

Comment: No, nothing except ports going up and down...

Comment: Try entering the command `logging buffered debug` to get more information in the logs.  Do you have power injectors or anything like that?